# Imagen en Drawable Obtener ruta URI Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Quisiera poder poner a mano una imagen "x" en la carpeta de Drawable de android y poder obtener la ruta Uri de esa imagen , para luego poder hacer

```
Img.setImageURI(aca quisiera la Uri de esa imagen que agrege a la carpeta Drwable)
```

el porque de esto es porque estoy obteniendo todos los contactos y su imagen la imagen lo tengo en formato uri y si no tiene imagen ese contacto quiero ponerle una que agrege yo a mi proyecto , como mi camino desde que agarra los datos hasta que los muestro es pasando por muchas activity quisiera poder obtener la URI de una imagen x que esta en la carpeta Drawable , desde ya gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cargar una imagen en `/drawable` a partir de su Uri.**

Si deseas usar el método [setImageURI()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI(android.net.Uri)) para cargar la imagen dentro de tu `ImageView`, es necesario especificar la ruta correcta al recurso, ya que de otra forma no se cargara, la ruta es `"android.resource://` y el `packagename` de tu proyecto.

La forma correcta de realizarlo es:

```
  Uri uriImage = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/"+R.drawable.imagen);
  imageView.setImageURI(uriImage);
```

En cambio, si únicamente especificas como `Uri` el recurso:

```
Uri uriImagen = Uri.parse("R.drawable.imagen");
```

esto no funcionara.

---

Incluso a partir de su `Uri` puedes obtener un `Drawable` y cargarlo en tu `ImageView` mediante el método `setImageDrawable()`:

```
String uri = "@drawable/imagen";
int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());
Drawable imagen = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), imageResource);
imageView.setImageDrawable(imagen);
```

Comment: Gracias jorge , sabes que revisando en el foro encontre esta mismo pregunta que le habias puesto a otro usuario , y tambien te deje un comentario diciendote que sos el uno , y te lo vuelvo a decir por aca , aparte de esto , sigo intentando ocultar el Dialogo de la llamada USSD , y aun no encuentro alguna forma chancha por decirlo de alguna forma , si se te ocurre algo al respecto gracias ! ,

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys, no me reocnoce ContextConmpat por qué es?

Comment: @wiki Agrega el import: import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es la Url del recurso puedes utilizar la clase `Uri` enviandolee como parametro el identificador del `drawable` asi:

```
Uri uriImagen = Uri.parse("R.drawable.mi_imagen");
```

Tambien puedes utilizar el metodo [`setImageResource(int resourceId)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)) del `ImageView` donde acepta el id del recurso para cargar la imagen:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mi_imagen);
```

Comment: intente usarlo Uri uriImagen = Uri.parse("R.drawable.mi_imagen"); aunque no eh tenido exito , necesitaria solo la uri ya que yo como dije primero hago un listado de todas las URI de las imagenes de los conctatos y lo que no tienen imagen de contacto queria ponerle una imagen que yo teng guardado en mipmap ,

Comment: Bruno, tienes que reemplazar `R.drawable.mi_imagen` por el nombre completo de tu recurso. Por ejemplo si el nombre es R.mipmap.imagen_usuario, eso tienes que poner dentro del string.

Comment: Jajja , sisi lo se , eso fue lo que hice , aunque no eh tenido exito ,